# Getting Checkbox Data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

Sorry to ask yet another simple question but program can be hard and like they say never be afraid to ask.
What I am trying to do is get jquery to detect if the checkbox has been click or not then when the user clicks the send button it will then go to PHP to say if it has been checked or not.

I have got form data to process to PHP such as the text fields but the check fields doesn't seem to want to work.

I have tried googling I have find nothing on my end

Here's the code

```
$(document).ready(function () {




    // Make a function that returns the data, then call it whenever you
    // need the current values
    function getData() {
        return {

            login_username: $('#login-username').val(),
            login_password: $('#login-password').val(),
          remember_me: $('#remember_me').find(":checked").val()

        }


    }

  $(":checkbox").click(function(){
    $("#remember_me").text(this.value)
  })
    $('#login_content').hover(function() {
$(this).css("background-color", "transparent");
    });

 $('#login_content').mouseleave(function() {
$(this).css("background-color", "white");
 });

$('.error').hover(function() {
$(this).css("background-color", "transparent");

});

$('.notice').hover(function() {
$(this).css("background-color", "transparent");

});


$('#login_content').mouseleave(function() {
$('.error').css("background-color", "#ffecec");
$('.notice').css("background-color", "#e3f7fc");
});



    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#background_cycler').fadeIn(1500);//fade the background back in once all the images are loaded
          // run every 7s
          setInterval('cycleImages()',4000);
    })




    function loading(e) {
        $('#login_try').show();
    }
    function hide_loading(e) {
    $('#login_try').hide();
    }

    function success_message(e) {
    $('#success_login').html("We're Just Signing You In");
    }



    function clearfields() {
        $('#login-username').val('');  //Clear the user login id field
        $('#login_password').val('');  //Clear the user login password field        
    }

    function check(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({

            url: 'check.php',
            type: 'post',
            error: function () {
                //If your response from the server is a statuscode error. do this!!!
                clearfields();
            },
            beforeSend: function () {

                loading(e);
            },
            data: {

            login_username: $('#login-username').val(), 
            login_password: $('#login-password').val(),






            }, // get current values







            success: function (data) {

                //if your response is a plain text. (e.g incorrect username or password)

                hide_loading(e);
                if(data.indexOf("<b>Welcome Back</b>") > -1) {
                hide_loading(e);
                success_message(e);
                }

                if(data.indexOf("You're Already Signed In!") > -1) {
                alert('This operation could not be proceeded');
                }


                $('#loading').fadeOut();
                $('#content').hide();
                $('#content').fadeIn(1000).html(data);

            }

        });

    }

    // Don't repeat so much; use the same function for both handlers
    $('#field').keyup(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            var username = $('#login-username').val();
            check(e);

        }
    });

    $('#submit_login').click(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode != 13) {

            check(e);

        }


    });

});
```

Comment: Where is your PHP code?

Comment: Where is your HTML code?

Comment: If I understood your problem correctly, this has nothing to do with JavaScript. I would encourage you to replace your JS snippet with some HTML and maybe even some PHP. Also, remove the `javascript` tag.

Comment: I carn't really give the PHP code out since I am using it in a project but php outputs the data with $_POST['data'];

Comment: HTML is just the form

Answer (score 0):

```
var isChecked = ($("#check_box_id").is(':checked')) ? 1 : 0;
//send this variable to the php file.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ;)
Just modified it to work with the code and it works ;)

Comment: if this did helped you, you can kindly accept this answer. good day!